# Open source or cheap PHP-based CRM solutions

Tags: php, crm

I am looking for CRM solutions.  This is for a mid-sized client, and we use mainly PHP.

I would like that solution to be easily customizable, ideally with an mvc structure.
I would like to avoid solutions such as sugarCRM, because the sugarCRM business model is meant to sell the non-free the full version, and sugarCRM has a reputation for bad code.

I prefer libre open-source code, but for such a project, a cheap package is ok.

Also, I have a specific interest in geomarketing.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I'll back you up on Sugar being "not the greatest code in the world" and it certainly has its quirks, but my company has deployed and maintained hundreds of instances of Sugar (free version) without incident.  I'd be willing to bet that 98% of the complaining is from those who are "getting their feet wet"

Answer (score 0):

What about Centric CRM? it's cheaper than sugarCRM and is generally well recommended.

Comment: The information available on http://www.concursive.com/show/centric-crm-41-stable-and-released is really limited. There is no list of features, no documentation apparently. Is this a new product ? has it been tested by real clients ?

Comment: Well both are based on J2EE/Java. I do know concursive is a private company but Intel invests in them and they are partnered with IBM. You can see a short relation between the 3 majors here: http://open-source-crm-guru.com/2008/07/25/sugarcrm-concursive-and-vtiger-open-source-crm-overview/ . Just depends on if you want a PHP or Java based solution. Centric is cheaper tho since CRM 3.0 is free, but support costs around 400$. I believe you can at least try out 4.1 for free too. I do know Centric CRM's monthly fee's are slightly cheaper than Sugar however.

Comment: oh. As said in the question, I want specifically PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard about Dolibarr, maybe you should give it a try. I didn't use it myself but the girl who managed customers at my last position was using it :)

Comment: It is written in PHP, has GN/GPL license, pretends to be simple, I'll give it a try. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Did you take a look at [vtiger](http://www.vtiger.com/)?

Comment: yes, I saw that one, and it the only item on my shortlist. Actually it seems to come first when "alternative to sugarCRM" is mentioned.

Comment: if you think sugarcrm has bad code, vtiger in comparison is *hell* code. i weep every time i have to deal with it...